# Return function pointer based on input type parameter C++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class for managing function pointers. I want to use a template or something to call the function stored in the class via the `[]` operator. For example, I can do `functions[malloc](0x123)`, which calls `malloc` via a pointer to the `malloc` function stored in the class. This is what I have:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
    
class DelayedFunctions
{
    decltype(&malloc) malloc;
    decltype(&free) free;
public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr T operator[](T)
    {
        if (std::is_same_v<T, decltype(&malloc)>)
            return malloc;
        if (std::is_same_v<T, decltype(&free)>)
            return free;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

I'm trying to get the template to expand/change the return type based on the function's arguments, but I'm not so sure how to go about getting it to work. The constructor which initializes the values of the private fields is omitted; all it does is get the addresses of the functions and then assign them to the fields. I'm trying to use C++20 to do this.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `std::function`?

Comment: Why must we add a few #include to compile your code? Do you not respect SO users?

Comment: no reason specifically, I just chose to do it manually @iBug.

Comment: I added headers I used @273K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works well with `if constexpr`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>

class DelayedFunctions
{
    decltype(&std::malloc) malloc = std::malloc;
    decltype(&std::free) free = std::free;
public:
    template <typename T>
    constexpr T operator[](T)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, decltype(&std::malloc)>)
            return malloc;
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, decltype(&std::free)>)
            return free;
        return {};
    }
};

DelayedFunctions functions;

int main() {
    auto *p = functions[malloc](123);
    functions[free](p);
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks. Why do we need constexpr in if blocks? I thought since constexpr is applied to the entire function the compiler should understand that control flow branches are constant?

Comment: Be careful, `consexpr func` and `constexpr if` are different language constructions. W/o the second one, the standard requires to compile the whole if statements, whereas by `constexpr if`, the standard requires to compile only true-branch.

Comment: *The compiler should understand that control flow branches are constant.* This is not true. Constexpr func can be called from runtime as a usual function.